# getContent() not returning actual vf page content

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component. In its init i have made a server call where i need to get content of my vf page. I have used getContent to achieve this. However when i debug this content i am not getting the actual content. This works in my vf page. But when i execute it through lightning it doesn't.

Apex Class:
    public class signDocumentController {

```
@AuraEnabled
public static String signDocument(){
    PageReference ref = Page.TestDocuSign;  
    ref.setRedirect(true);
    Blob content = ref.getContent();
    String file_contents = content.toString();
    system.debug('content iss'+file_contents );
    return null;
}
```

}

My vf page whose content i need:

`<apex:page >
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>
  This is your new Page
  <br />
  <br />
  &nbsp;
  <p>Signature: <span style="color:white;">signer1sig</span></p>
  <p>Date: <span style="color:white;">signer1date</span></p>
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
   </apex:page>`

Actual Content on executing:
[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you have `ref.setRedirect(true);` in there? Have you tried without?

Comment: @rael_kid nothing specific. I was trying out a few things. I did try without it as well.

Comment: Is not it because you are returning `return null;` instead of `return file_contents;` on signDocument?

Comment: In the debug logs itself i am not getting the actual content.

Comment: I have an issue. In Lighting getContent() returns garbage. Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I have a similar issue now.  Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue & Salesforce support fixed it for me by building an explicit URL to the VisualForce page.  Here's the change they made to my code.

```
String vfHostname = DomainCreator.getVisualforceHostname('c'); //Get the Visualforce hostname
String vfPageUrl = 'https://' + vfHostname + '/apex/QuotePDF_EU?id=' + quoteId; //Build the URL
PageReference pdf = new PageReference(vfPageUrl);
```